# RubyMotion - error build vendor project - how to get details

Tags: rubymotion

I am trying to build simple project cloned from github (cocosmotion), and I am continuosly getting the exactly same error - "ERROR! Building vendor project 'vendor\cocos2d-iphone' failed to create at least one '.a' library."
I think that is not much of a problem if there is a way to get some details, logs or something similar information, which can help to solve this kind of problem. But all my tries and searches in google are not helpful at the moment.

So my question is - How can I get more detailed information about what is failing to build in that vendor project?
Are there a way to turn on more verbose output?

Comment: Can you confirm whether it builds properly in XCode? I had a similar problem and it was due to a misconfigured scheme. There's also an issue where you may have to open a project up into Xcode briefly before RubyMotion will be able to build it.

Comment: I confirm that! That was suprising - because XCode didn't mention any problems, while it's command line tool was interpreting as an error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well actually it turned out that all I need is to do "rake clean" and try to build again after that. This will force total rebuild and I was able to see problems in vendor project compilation process (which was deprecated calls in cocos2d source code which was not latest version).